# MySQL: AND + Parameter selecting and skipping issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

My issue relates to this already solved [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596466/how-to-select-or-skip-to-the-next-row-if-meets-certain-criteria), but I just cannot get it working.

So I have this query, that should filter first for the column 'type' and then for the smallest timestamp in the column 'lastChange'. The timestamps will be updated frequently.

```
SELECT * FROM api 
WHERE (type = 'Public') AND (lastChange = ( SELECT MIN(lastChange) FROM api ));
```

It appears to filter the values, because when I reach a row that holds type = 'Private' the result would be empty.

```
type != 'Public' // doesn't work either, because I have more than two values
```

But shouldn't the query actually skip all rows that do not hold the type = 'Public' and only return only the those ones with a positive result - how can I achieve this properly?

Comment: If you're just trying to find the latest one, `WHERE \`type\` = 'Public' ORDER BY lastChange desc LIMIT 1` should work. Note the backticks around `type`, as it's a special word in MySQL.

Comment: I cannot upvote the above comment enough.  It's the way to solve this problem, *and*  it contains a pro tip about a probable error you have in your query.

Comment: @aynber there's no need to tick `TYPE` since it's only a keyword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html and not reserved. There's no `(R)` next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT on the right to lastChange return one minimum valie for all records, but you need MIN value only for Public type, you need specify that in query.

```
SELECT * FROM api 
WHERE (type = 'Public') 
AND (lastChange = ( 
    SELECT MIN(lastChange) 
    FROM api AS t2 
    WHERE t2.type = "Public"
    )
);
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.